# Warn => Failed to decode downloaded font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I getting this warn in my console when i starting my app. (this happen when i try to add fontFamily to the style={{fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium'}}). When i using index.css all fonts break (just using defaults fonts sans-serif)

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/cards/static/media/AnyConv.com__Poppins-Medium.9bf6eb6e76457e197444.woff2
```

This my code:

````
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PoppinsMedium';
    src: url('common/fonts/AnyConv.com__Poppins-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('common/fonts/AnyConv.com__Poppins-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
    url('common/fonts/AnyConv.com__Poppins-Medium.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('common/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'PoppinsMedium', sans-serif;
}


}```


fonts based on this way: src/common/fonts/
(p.s using "baseUrl": "src",)

When i adding fonts like this i getting warninig in my console. How to repair?
````